# How to limit wifi bandwidth from router (make ethernet priority) on cisco router?

Tags: networking, qos

There is 3 PCs on the network in our house (1. WiFi, 2. WiFi, 3. Ethernet)

Whenever the first one is using the WiFi and I am using the internet I lag so much whenever I play a game or just browsing the internet. Now I don't understand why this happens only when the first one is turned on (if the second one is on the one with ethernet takes priority) and I don't really care, I just want to fix this in any way possible

I tried disabling WMM but nothing changed.

I've uploaded a [short webm](https://webmshare.com/mx1m9) of my router options because I honestly don't know what to edit or if it's even possible with my router, hope someone can help me.

Comment: Disabling WMM is certainly not the answer since it is the expression of quality of service in a WiFi context. Please edit your question with more information because as of now, we don't know what machine you are using. Make it as detailed as you can, give context on your network, what kind of hardware you're using... Thank you.

Comment: @Doezer I'm just looking for a way to limit wifi bandwidth, any way to do so is the right solution for me. I'm sure there is some in my router options but I don't know what to edit.

Comment: @Doezer where can I find the network information that you need?

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot see the webm at work as the website is blocked. Most likely you will find this kind of option (if it exists) in general security or access settings. But seeing your post, it is likely to be a station problem (bad quality interface or the likes)